# Dataset Operation on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am pretty new to Spark on Scala especially using Dataset. I have a dataset that looks like this

```
+----------+-----------+--------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|customerId|   forename| surname|            accounts|numberAccounts|totalBalance|averageBalance|
+----------+-----------+--------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|   IND0001|Christopher|   Black|              [null]|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0002|  Madeleine|    Kerr|[[IND0002,ACC0262...|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0002|  Madeleine|    Kerr|[[IND0002,ACC0155...|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0003|      Sarah| Skinner|[[IND0003,ACC0540...|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0003|      Sarah| Skinner|[[IND0003,ACC0486...|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0003|      Sarah| Skinner|[[IND0003,ACC0235...|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
```

I want the dataset to to produce a a new dataset like this

```
+----------+-----------+--------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|customerId|   forename| surname|            accounts|numberAccounts|totalBalance|averageBalance|
+----------+-----------+--------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|   IND0001|Christopher|   Black|              [null]|        234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0002|  Madeleine|    Kerr|[[IND0002,ACC0262,65], [IND0002,ACC0155,98]]|234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
|   IND0003|      Sarah| Skinner|[[IND0003,ACC0540,76],[IND0003,ACC0486,89],[IND0003,ACC0235,23]]| 234454|    99949494|       50000.0|
```

I don't want to use the import spark.sql.functions._
any suggestion on what function I could use?

```
  val joinedData = customerDS
    .joinWith(
      accountDS,
      customerDS("customerId") === accountDS("customerId"),
      "left"
    )
  val mappedData = joinedData.map{
    case(c,a) => CustomerAccountOutput(c.customerId, c.forename, c.surname, Seq(a), 234454, 99949494, (100000/2))

  }
```

some part of my code

Comment: could you show some code or if it is possible provide a [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's not clear what is your issue. Sounds like you want to do some grouping. Maybe [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#GroupByLink) is what you need?

Comment: I have used some case classes. I tried using a groupBy but it didn't work

Comment: Do you mean you need a Spark command to make the upper dataset look like the lower dataset?

Without using spark.sql.functions, you can just call `.dropDuplicates("customerId")` on your dataset, which will keep only the first row for each unique `customerId`.

This will do what you're showing, unless you actually mean something else.

Comment: I solved my problem by using groupbyKey and mapGroup